# Why does my shell script display different output if each command is run individually?

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
keyExists=`stat ~/.ssh/id_rsa &> /dev/null; echo $?`
echo $keyExists
```

When I run it as `./test.sh` or `sh test.sh` it outputs

```
0 File: `/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa' Size: 0 Blocks: 0 IO Block: 4096 regular empty file Device: fc00h/64512d Inode: 2888560 Links: 1 Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--) Uid: ( 1000/ vagrant) Gid: ( 1000/ vagrant) Access: 2014-07-23 11:40:33.355848310 -0400 Modify: 2014-07-23 11:40:33.355848310 -0400 Change: 2014-07-23 11:40:33.355848310 -0400 Birth: -
```

However when I run each command individually on the command line

```
keyExists=`stat ~/.ssh/id_rsa &> /dev/null; echo $?`
echo $keyExists
```

I get the output

```
0
```

Why am I seeing this additional output and how do I suppress this additional output when I run the shell script?

Comment: Maybe using `/bin/sh` runs `sh` instead of `bash`, or if it's `bash`, turns off `bash4` enhancements?  `&>` is functional only in `bash` 4 and later.

Comment: `&>` is available in earlier versions of `bash` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before testing, make sure your current shell is `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`.

As far as I known: `&>` is a new feature in `bash`, not in the old `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `&>/dev/null` do it as `>/dev/null 2>&1`. This would make your script work even with ancient `sh` shells. You can also change your header to `#!/bin/bash` if you indeed have bash. Or see output of `which bash` to know.